# modal window to open when icon is clicked

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a couple of form definitions in my main HTML file.

I would like to display these forms in a modal window, when the user performs certain action, such as click on an icon.

I have followed an article on how to do it for links (hrefs). But now my requirement is [to get the same working for clicking on an icon.](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

Thank you,
Harriet

Comment: What have you tried so far and did not work? It is expected that you at least attempt to code it yourself. Please refer to this link on [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried the example as can be found in the link above. I then decided to use icons. Icons does not have href attributes. I was looking for an alternative way. I found one in the meantime, so if anyone was actually thinking of actually helping out - I am sorted - thank you.

Comment: A modal should open after a click on a `button`: this is the element dedicated for this type of action. Worst case: using a link (w/ `role="button"`). So just put your icon in a button or a link, be sure to add relevant text describing what this button does (you can `.visually-hidden` or `.element-invisible` this text, it'll be perceivable by screen readers but not visually perceived). Examples working with mouse, keyboard and touch: [NCSU](https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/blog/2013/09/13/the-incredible-accessible-modal-dialog/) and [Nicolas Hoffmann](http://a11y.nicolas-hoffmann.net/modal/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to write a java function, that will explicitly set the location of the window to where you want the url to point - example:

```
function openPreferences() {
    window.location = '#openPreferences';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple solution would be to create a LinkBlock Element and set the Background to the Icon's Image, which will allow you to turn it into a Link, thus further allowing you to open your Modal Window with it.. Simply create your Modal as Display None, and upon clicking the LinkBlock (with your Icon as the Background), make it change the Modal property to Display Block, etc.